# Prove that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}{n^3}$ does not exist, using the $\varepsilon-N$ definition of a limit.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

My proof is as follows:

Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}{n^3}=L$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then for $n>N\in\mathbb{N}$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
|n^3-L|&<&\varepsilon \\
|n^3|-|L|&<&\varepsilon \\
n^3&<&\varepsilon+|L| \\
n&<&(\varepsilon+|L|)^{1/3}
\end{eqnarray*}
Which contradicts that the limit is $L$ for all $n>N$.

Is this valid?

Comment: The equality $|x-y| = |x|-|y|$ is certainly not true in general.

Comment: Never said it was. $|x|-|y|\leq||x|-|y||\leq|x-y|$ which means if $|x-y|<\varepsilon$, then so is $|x|-|y|$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry. I thought you were claiming that these conditions were equivalent.

Comment: By definition, $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^3=l$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $n>N$ implies that $|n^3-l|<\varepsilon$. Therefore, if it is not true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^3=l$, then *there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $N\in\mathbb N$, there is an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n>N$ and $|n^3-l|\ge\varepsilon$.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having written “Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then” you should have added “there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that”.

And then, after $n>N\in\Bbb N$, you wrote four assertions without saying what's connecting them. You should have written:\begin{align}\left|n^3-L\right|<\varepsilon\implies&\left|n^3\right|-|L|<\varepsilon\\\iff&n^3<\varepsilon+|L|\\\iff&n<\sqrt[3]{\varepsilon+|L|}.\end{align}

Comment: Do I always require the 'implies' symbols? And so if I add those (plus the other corrections), the proof is complete, right?

Comment: You must put *something* that tells us what's connecting those assertions. Also, the final sentence makes no sense. It should be “Which contradicts that the inequality holds for all $n>N$.”